# Django Complex Query: combined output

Tags: django, django-models

## models.py

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_type

class Device(models.Model):
    device_type         = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType,to_field='device_type')
    serial_number       = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    in_use_by           = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    brand               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    model               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    type_number         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    mac_address         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
```

Above is my models.py file. I want to write a query such that I get the output in the following format:

```
device_type-serial_number-model-brand
```

Comment: A list of *all* strings, one per `Device`?

Comment: Suppose, I have 3 devices then, the ouput I am expecting is a Queryset with 3 values but in the above written format.

Comment: Yes, but what is an *element* of a queryset? A string?

Comment: yes all are basically strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Processing in *Python*

We can generate a list containing such strings and let Python construct these strings as follows:

```
list(map(
    '-'.join,
    Devices.objects.values_list(
        'device_type__device_type',
        'serial_number',
        'model',
        'brand'
    )
)
```

This will return a `list` of `str`ings.

## Processing at the *database*

We can also perform the concatenation at the database, and then we have a *queryset* of strings:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Devices.objects.annotate(
    text=Concat(
        F('device_type__device_type'),
        Value('-'),
        F('serial_number'),
        Value('-'),
        F('model'),
        Value('-'),
        F('brand')
    )
).values_list('text', flat=True)
```

Comment: Can we use a where clause?

Comment: You can `filter`, for example at the `Devices.objects.filter(brand__icontains="Ace").annotate(...)`, or after the annotation: `Devices.objects.annotate(total=...).filter(text__icontains='bla')`.